# How to convert hyphen in text list to HTML list items using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

How can I convert a plain text list into a HTML list using regex in PHP?

```
Lorem ipsum.

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
- item 4

Dolores amet.
```

Into

```
Lorem ipsum.

<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
<li>item4</li>
</ul>

Dolores amet.
```

Comment: So, as you said, using rexex, but what have you tried?

Comment: If that's a well-defined format (it looks like markdown) there's possibly a library that will do it for you.

Comment: If you're looking for a markdown parser (which would be able to easily handle this), I would recommend [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org).

Answer (score 1):

1. Regex pattern

   ```
   \n\s?-\s?(.*)
   ```

   > example https://regex101.com/r/zQ7xL6/1
2. Getting the matches.

   For getting every match use [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/preg-match-all):

   `preg_match_all($pattern, $your_text, $matches);`

   ```
   Array (
     [0] => Array (
       [0] => 'item 1'
     )
     [1] => Array (
       [0] => 'item 2'
     )
     etc..
    )
   ```
3. HTML

   Here you can do everything you want with your matches. So let's add some HTML tags.

   ```
   $html_text = '';
   foreach($matches as $match) {
     $item = $match[0]; //item 1
     $html_text .= '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
   }
   $html_text = '<ul>' . $html_text . '</ul>';
   ```

Output

```
    <ul>
     <li>item1</li>
     <li>item2</li>
     <li>item3</li>
     <li>item4</li>
    </ul>
```

4. **preg_replace way**

   For inspiration look here [A regex that converts text lists to html in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344563/a-regex-that-converts-text-lists-to-html-in-php?rq=1) hope I helped you.

Comment: I know this is relatively old, but I believe your code should be "$matches[1] as $match" and "$item = $match". Otherwise, it doesn't execute properly.