# Converting HTML ordered/unordered list to plain text in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, html-lists

I have some HTML ordered/ unordered list in HTML. As I want to export it to a txt file, I need to convert it to plain text.

eg. Original HTML:

```
<ol><li>Item 1</li></li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ol>
```

I want to change it to

```
1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3
```

I searched on StackOverflow but only found a solution of the opposite conversion. [A regex that converts text lists to html in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344563/a-regex-that-converts-text-lists-to-html-in-php)

Is there any ways I can handle it? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, there is an error in the original HTML, the second li tag starts with </li>, instead of <li>.

Comment: You want HTML rendered output to be saved in a text file?

Comment: Do you want to know how to convert HTML to text using PHP? Or will any way be acceptable? Perhaps XSLT could be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the tags you do not need and explode it on a tag that will return itself for every row.

```php
<?php
$html = '
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
';

$html = str_replace(['<ol>', '</ol>', '</li>'], '', $html);
$html = explode('<li>', $html);

print_r($html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little more complicated than just regex, especially if you want to add the numbers in front. But this little piece of code wil translate `<ol><li>Item 1</li></li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ol>`
 to

```
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3
```

```
<?php

$string = "<ol><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ol>";

$string= preg_replace("/<li>/", " * ", $string);
$string= preg_replace("/<\/li>/", "\n", $string);
$string= preg_replace("/<\/?ol>/", "", $string);

echo $string;
```

Comment: `*` does not represent an _ordered_ list though. This could work for _unordered_ lists

Comment: As I said, you're going to have to loop through the list to add numbers, as far as I know, you can't loop through and add numbers in a regex.

Comment: Remember - the user has placed the name "Item 1" in as an example that it is item 1, it does not mean the item would have a number in it.

Comment: I know, but if he wants an ordered list, he could make a for-loop that adds a number to each line or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [html2text](https://github.com/voku/html2text/tree/master) library. It has different methods to convert your `HTML` string into plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to remember here that the numbers mentioned in the LI tags aren't to be used as a reference as they might be "donkey", "lamb", "monkey".

My solution matches anything inside the LI tags and then loops on the matches to create the item numbers.

The preg_match_all will create an array with sub-arrays. The first contains the whole match including the LI tags and the second will just match whatever was found inside the (.*?) non-greedy area.

I have used \n as a line break but if it was HTML output that would be a BR tag obviously

```
$str = "<ol><li>Monkey</li></li><li>Lamb</li><li>Elephant</li></ol>";
preg_match_all("/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/i",$str,$matches);
if(count($matches[1])>0){
    foreach($matches[1] as $k=>$v){
        echo ($k+1).". $v\n";
    }
}
```